# Page skip(when called one page in to another page) ionic view app after adding ionic.bundle.js

Tags: javascript, css, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I'm working on ionic application its almost working fine,Here I need to add image on on-click  zoom in zoom out, then applyed one css

```
/*object image zoom in zoom out*/
.objImg {
    transition: -webkit-transform 2.65s ease;
    transition:transform 1.25s ease;
}

.objImg:active {
    -webkit-transform: scale(2);
    transform:scale(2);
}
```

This function not affecting in ionic view app. after i added ionic.bundle.js file the zoom in zoom out worked nice. but after clicking back button page is going skip.

Example: I Have Three HTML pages (1 2 3)
when I click back button on page_3 coming page_2 then directly go to page_1(skipping page_2 issue affecting).

calling like this back button onclick=functionName();

```
function functionname() {

   var previousppagesrc =variable1;
   var language =variable2;
   var folderName =variable3;


    document.getElementById("backbtnId").href = "" + variable1+ "?language=" + variable2+ "?studyset=" + variable3+ "";
```

}